# What is the fastest way to check if a convex solid is completely inside another convex solid?

Tags: geometry, collision-detection, linear-algebra, computational-geometry

I have two different convex objects that I need to check three different states regarding their positions:

1. The solids are not colliding
2. The solids are partially colliding
3. One of the solids is completely inside the other

I am using the GJK algorithm to check if the solids are colliding, so that eliminates the 1 state. Now the problem is that the GJK cant tell if I have a partial collision or if one of the objects is completely inside the other. What is the fastest way to check the third state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create an AXIS-Aligned bounding box(AABB) for the two objects.

   - If they(AABB's) do not clash, the bodies are outside / no collission.
2. If the AABB's do :

   - Intersect all faces/edges of one with the other bodies faces/edges.( you can again eliminate non collissions with AABB as above for every face-face pair etc )
3. If nothing else, they are one within the other.

The following presentation is quite a good resource. I recommend a read : http://www.sccg.sk/~durikovic/classes/CGAnim/ca10_lesson04.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Establish the oriented plane equation of all faces of the first solid (take three vertexes in every face) and check that all vertexes of the second solid lie on the positive side of the planes.

Takes time O(N.M) for N faces and M vertexes.